# Can we emit a signal from a public slot

Tags: c++, qt

```
class MyMainWindow:public QMainWindow {
    public:
        MyWindow* myWindow() { return myWindow ;}
    private:
        MyWindow* myWindow;
};

class MyWindow:public Qobject {
    private slot:
        void mySlot();
};

class MyWindow2: class QWidget {
    public slot:
        void refreshClick();
    signals:
        signal1();
};

MyWindow2::MyWindow2(QMainWindow* parent) {
    QPushButton* refresh;
    QObject::connect(refresh,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(refreshClicked()));

    if(parent) {
         QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(signal1),parent->myWindow(),SLOT(mySlot));
    }
```

}

```
void MyWindow2::refreshClicked(){
    emit signal1();
}
```

I want to know if it is legal to emit signal1 from slot refreshClicked and also are there any cons of emitting a signal from within a slot

Comment: Yes, it's legal. Emitting signal is basically doing a function call to all connected slots immediately (unless it is queued connection, which happens between threads or if you specifiy it with `connect` call). Just out of curiosity, where would you then emit signals, if not in slots?

Comment: Treat slots as general functions and ask the same question again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly ok. But if your only goal is to "forward" a signal, you can also connect your "incoming" signal directly to the signal you are emmitting. eg.:

```
connect(advisor   , SIGNAL(hasAdvice()),
        this      , SIGNAL(executeAdvice())
       )
```

But keep in mind that this does not always benefit the extendablity of your code.